# It's not that big a deal? Why is 'a' needed?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I have only known the expression, "it's not a big deal".

Just now I got to know there is another expression, "it's not that big **a** deal". I wonder why it is not used like "it's not that big deal'. Why is 'a' needed? Then can I say, "that big an apple, that small a house"? Or just an idiom adapted only to that expression?

Comment: I can't explain the grammar, but you need the "a", and yes, "that big an apple" and "that small a house" are correct and natural. Same with "**so** big an apple", etc.

Comment: **Deal** is a countable noun, just like *house* and *apple*.  You can't refer to it with a determiner.